# Operator value evalution issue in C program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){

     int i;
     i = i-3;
     printf("%d",i); // output -3
}
```

Why answer is 3 every time run this c program. but we knows c picks random value for variable which is not initialized. so why it gives -3. I also try it using auto storage class. I am using codeblocks compiler.

Comment: Who said C picks a random value for unitialized variables?

Comment: C doesn't really pick random values for uninitialized (local) variables. At least in most cases, it simply uses whatever value happens to be in those memory locations. Depending on circumstances, (some of) those *might* happen to have some particularly values, at least one some particular platform, with some particular compiler, etc.

Comment: The uninitialized value of i is zero in this case. Nothing unusual. Still, never rely on uninitialized values being any specific value in C.

Comment: "Why answer is 3 every time run this c program" - why it can't be 3, The value is unpredictable which means it can be 3 100 times and 0 at any time or any other value

Comment: It's undefined behavior, just anything can happen, even it looks fine this time.

Comment: What is your point @JoshuaTaylor

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, *not* `void main()`. If your textbook told you to use `void main()`, its author doesn't know the language; find a better book.

Comment: Don't confuse "random" with "arbitrary".

Comment: @Jarvish to say that a variable is initialized with a random value makes it sound like the compiler is doing (without telling you) `int i = random_value()`.  It's unlike that it would do that though, since it's more work.  it just doesn't guarantee you what value _will_ be there.  It's sort of like how someone might very predictably walk the same route to work every morning;  it's not random at all, but it's not a guarantee that they've made to you,  they could decide to do something different tomorrow.  As KeithThompon said, "don't confuse random with arbitrary."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code has following Error:**

Uninitialized local variable 'i' used.

**Incorrect Statments >>>**

> Xx. we knows c picks random value for variable which is not initialized .xX

Answer (score 3):

Your code is causing undefined behavior. Anything could happen in the code. Your code might print 3 or 300 or a Mona Lisa picture on the screen.

6.3.2.1p2:

If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.